# Adding line when converting string to text file

Tags: python, text-files

**Python**

I have 1000+ files with numerically consecutive names like `IMAG0000.JPG` that I have saved as list, converted to string, and saved as a text file. I want the text file to look like this:

```
IMAG0000.JPG
IMAG0001.JPG
IMAG0002.JPG
IMAG0003.JPG
...
```

Currently, it looks like:

```
IMAG0000.JPGIMAG0001.JPGIMAG0002.JPGIMAG0003.JPG...
```

I can't quite figure out where to put \n to make it format correctly. This is what I have so far...

```
import glob

newfiles=[]
filenames=glob.glob('*.JPG')
newfiles =''.join(filenames)

f=open('file.txt','w')
f.write(newfiles)
```

Comment: '\n'.join(filenames) perhaps

Comment: Use `'\n'.join(filenames)` instead of `''.join(filenames)`

Comment: don't forget to close the file handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
newfiles = '\n'.join(filenames)
```

Side note: [it's good practice to use the `with` keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) when dealing with file objects, so the code:

```
f=open('file.txt','w')
f.write(newfiles)
```

would become:

```
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(newfiles)
```

That way you do not need to explicitly do `f.close()` to close the file.

Answer (score 3):

You concat with an empty string `''` instead of `'\n'`.

```
newfiles = '\n'.join(filenames)
f = open('file.txt','w')
f.write(newfiles) # keep in mind to use f.close()
```

or safer (i.e. releasing the file handle):

```
with open("file.txt", w) as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(filenames))
```

or instead of concatting everything:

```
with open("file.txt", w) as f:
    for filename in filenames:
        f.write(filename + '\n')
```